# how can I run imacros from the command line?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

I have a script that I am writing, and it uses an imacros macro.

in Windows, one would use something like: `"google-chrome-stable imacros://run/?m=/Path/to/Macro/macro.iim"`

On the Ubuntu command line, this does not work (properly). Chrome will load, 
but imacros will not load. I have installed file system access to the imacros macro system, my macros are in `/home/$USER/imacros/macros/`

I have tried:

```
google-chrome-stable  imacros://run/?m=/home/user/imacros/macros/iwin.iim
google-chrome-stable  | imacros://run/?m=/home/user/imacros/macros/iwin.iim
```

how can I call imacros from the command line to execute my macro?

Comment: did you see this [wiki](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Chrome) ?

Comment: yes, but the examples are for windows. Argh, this is such BS, it works in fire fox,  but not in google-chrome like this: `firefox imacros://run/?m=macro.iim`  its BS, because the website it goes to openly thwarts firefox.